# Can´t run tests with "npm test"

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I have this exercises, and a test file, and when a want to run that test I got this...

```
00-IntroToCS/homework (master)       
$ npm test

> prep@1.0.0 test 00-IntroToCS\homework
> jest --collectCoverage=false CS.test.js

No tests found
In 00-IntroToCS\homework
  5 files checked.
  testMatch: **/__tests__/**/*.js?(x),**/?(*.)(spec|test).js?(x) - 1 match
  testPathIgnorePatterns: \\node_modules\\ - 5 matches
Pattern: CS.test.js - 0 matches
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

I dont know too much about npm yet, this is a homework from a Bootcamp and I want to run the test file.

Comment: Can you show the CS.test.js file?

Answer (score 0):

whats in your package.json file under the scripts section?

also try using

```
npm test -- SomeTestFileToRun
```

if youre just testing one file.

Comment: "scripts": {
            "test": "jest --collectCoverage=false CS.test.js",
            "grade": "jest --useStderr --json --outputFile=./tests/result.json"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
            "eslint": "^4.13.1",
            "jest": "^22.0.3",
            "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
            "prompt-sync": "^4.2.0"
      },
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "jest": {
            "testURL": "http://localhost/"
      }

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution! The problem was the directory: `PROGRAMA CION(16-12-20)\HENRY (08-02-21)`, the white spaces were the problem...